# How to create AVD for tablet?

Tags: android, emulation, tablet

After many search, I know there are similar questions about this, but seems they are either out-dated, or not what I am looking for.

I want the AVD works as this: in system Settings, the screen should be split to two parts, left part shows all headers, while right part shows the fragment for selected header. I tried many ways, but the emulator always show the fragment in a new activity.

PS, I am using 4.0+ AVD. Some links says I need to use Android 3.0-3.2 image, but Android SDK Manager does not provide image for old version anymore.

What can I do? Thanks.

EDIT:
I start the SDK Manager from inside Android Studio. There is no "ARM EABI v7a System Image" under 3.0-3.2. See below screen shot. I also created huge screen emulator (10.1 WXGA Tablet, 800x1280 mdpi, Android 5.0.1 armeabi-v7a, WXGA800 skin), but the Settings is still same with normal phone.
[image]

Comment: My SDK Manager still provides Android 3.0-3.2

Comment: What AVD Manager are you using? The one in Android Studio, or the classic one? In either case, you're looking to to choose a device with a screen size big enough for the two-pane Settings -- 10.1" will work, smaller than that may or may not work.